# Yii2 загрузить страницу с параметрами через view

Tags: php, yii2, виджет, navigationbar

Есть view с таблицей и навигацией. В таблице выводятся данные, в зависимости от входящего параметра. Однако, когда переходишь по ссылке через Nav, выдает ошибку, что страница не найдена, хотя если вручную вбить то же самое, то все работает нормально. Подскажите, как исправить ошибку, или же какой альтернативный метод можно использовать? Спасибо.

```
        <?php
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-default nav-pills nav-justified'],
    'items' => [
        ['label' => 'N5', 'url' => ['kandji/index&level=5']],
        ['label' => 'N4', 'url' => ['kandji/index&level=4']],
        ['label' => 'N3', 'url' => ['kandji/index&level=3']],
        ['label' => 'N2', 'url' => ['kandji/index&level=2']],
        ['label' => 'N1', 'url' => ['kandji/index&level=1']]
    ],
]);
?>
```

Comment: `kandji/index&level=5` - попробуйте исправить на `/kandji/index&level=5`. и так со всеми

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы, в данном случае нужно вместо

```
['label' => 'N5', 'url' => ['kandji/index&level=5']],
```

Писать

```
['label' => 'N5', 'url' => ['/kandji/index','level' => '5']]
```